# Show B when you mouseover A and hide B when you mouseover C?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

The CSS:

```
<div class="aaa">aaa</div>
<div class="bbb">bbb</div> 
<div class="ccc">ccc</div>


<hr>

<div class="aaa">aaa</div>
<div class="bbb">bbb</div> 
<div class="ccc">ccc</div> 


<hr>

<div class="aaa">aaa</div>
<div class="bbb">bbb</div> 
<div class="ccc">ccc</div>
```

I've been trying to figure out how I can do this. I tried the following but it doesn't make sense since it's removing the hide class from ccc instead of bbb

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aaa").on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).nextAll('.bbb:first').addClass('hide');
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $(this).nextAll('.ccc:first').removeClass('hide');    
        }
    });
});
```

[**MY JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/604/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you told it to remove the hide class from `ccc` when you wrote `$(this).nextAll('.ccc:first')`.

You probably want something like this:

```
$(".aaa").on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.bbb:first').addClass('hide');
    }
});

$(".ccc").on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $(this).prevAll('.bbb:first').removeClass('hide');    
    }
});
```